# Why accuracy over each k-fold cross-Validation differ alot? how can i improve that

Tags: model, cross-validation, evaluation, fold

I have a data set with 91 Obervsation with 700 features. I have reduced the dimension of data using PCA. Then I split the data-set into training and test with ratio= 70/30. After that applied kfold =10 cross-validations on training data set and compute accuracy over each fold. I suspected that it varied a lot.

class distribution in datasets

```
Male Female 
47     44
```

This is accuracy over each fold? result over each fold when training a model using LDA

```
fold1 = 0.71
fold2 = 0.83
fold3 = 0.50
fold4 0.29,
fold5 = 0.67 ,
fold6 = 0.33
fold7 = 0.14
fold8 = 1.00
fold9 = 0.33
fold10 = 0.14
```

Is it correct to have such variation? If not, then how can I solve that problem?
How can I improve my accuracy over each fold at least it should not vary much?
What will be the possible reason for that? Why it vary a lot?
I am looking for an answer to these questions

**Here is my Cross-validation function**

The **training_data** data is the 70% percent of actual data

```
    lda_cv = function(training_data,k_number_of_folds){


  training_data = training_data[sample(nrow(training_data)),]
  #creating folds
  folds <- createFolds(training_data$class,k_number_of_folds)
  result = list("t_cfm"=NULL,"t_accuracy"=NULL)
  for (i in 1:k_number_of_folds) {
    
    #index <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
    index <- folds[[i]]
    train <- training_data[-index, ]
    test <- training_data[index, ]
    
    ##testing accuracy
    lda.res = lda( as.factor(class) ~ . , data = train)
    lda.pred= predict(lda.res,newdata = test)
    
    cfm  = table(lda.pred$class,test$class,dnn = c("predicted","Actual"))
    
    result$t_cfm[[i]] = cfm
    accuracy = round(mean(lda.pred$class ==test$class),2)
    
    result$t_accuracy[[i]] = accuracy
    
    }
  
     return(result)
  
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have selected the highest variance/most informative features from PCA?

Comment: Adding code (and possibly sample data) would help us debug

Comment: Sorry, I can't share Data because it confidential but I can share the code. YES, I have selected the component from PCA with the highest variance.
The first 2 components represent most of the variance in my case.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is. because each fold is training on a set of images that is different from the other, and maybe one of them is having way too much noisy images